# Array.length problem in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've written this sample code to print the length of x. But for some reason, I am not getting anything! Help!

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function myF()
{
   var x = [1,2,3,4];
   var y = document.getElementById("thing");
   y.innerHtml = x.length;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload = "myF();" >

<div id = "thing" >
PRINT TEST
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The property name is innerHTML rather than innerHtml.

Comment: Why does the Firefox error console not return an error when this is done?

Comment: @Unkwntech: Why should it? DOM nodes are objects, so you're free to add any property you like - even ones named 'innerHtml'...

Comment: @Unkwntech: Because That's JavaScript's syntax to assign new properties to instantiated objects. So what happened in that line was the object stored in 'y' had a new property name 'innerHtml' attached and assigned the length of array x.

Comment: I thought so, it was asked for the sake of the question asker.

Comment: I'd look at using jQuery(el).html() instead. It'll be future proof.